# Mysql: Setup the format of DATETIME to 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' when creating a table

Tags: mysql, datetime, command-line, format, create-table

After googling around, I cannot find a way to create a new table with a `DATETIME` column with the default format set to '`DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`'

I saw a tutorial in which it was done in `phpmyadmin` so I suspect that I could use mysql via command line and achieve the same thing when creating my new table with

```
CREATE TABLE ()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think while creating table you can change format

Answer (score 91, accepted):

"MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format."
This is from mysql site. You can store only this type, but you can use one of the many time format functions to change it, when you need to display it.

[Mysql Time and Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

For example, one of those functions is the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), which can be used like so:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') FROM tablename
```

Comment: To get the current datetime using PHP's `date()` function, use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`.

Answer (score 19):

Use DATE_FORMAT function to change the format.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename
```

Refer [DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) for more details

Answer (score 9):

As others have explained that it is not possible, but here's alternative solution, it requires a little tuning, but it works like datetime column.

I started to think, how I could make formatting possible. I got an idea. What about making trigger for it? I mean, adding column with type `char`, and then updating that column using a MySQL trigger. And that worked! I made some research related to triggers, and finally come up with these queries:

```
CREATE TRIGGER timestampper BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH
ROW SET NEW.timestamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER timestampper BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH
ROW SET NEW.timestamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

You can't use `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` as a column type, because these have their own format, and they update automatically.

So, here's your alternative timestamp or datetime alternative! Hope this helped, at least I'm glad that I got this working.

Comment: This idea is really awesome! But what if you're inserting values from a file? I mean how will this work for `LOAD DATA INFILE` query?

Comment: By using CHAR as the data type of the column you will loose correct sorting and calculations based on that field as it will no longer actually be a date.

Answer (score 5):

i have used following line of code & it works fine Thanks.... @Mithun Sasidharan
**

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename

**

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty certain that you can't change the datetime format in mysql.  The phpmyadmin setting is probably applying a custom format as it reads the datetime (using DATE_FORMAT or something from php).  It shouldn't matter what format the database uses, format in the application to display it as you wish.

Date formatting is a pretty common task.  I typically like to abstract it out into internationalization code or, if you don't need to deal with i18n, into a common date utility library.  It helps keep things consistent and makes it easier to change later (or add i18n support).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I read about the DATE_FORMAT function as a way to get the format that I want.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't; datetime will be stored in default format only while creating table and then you can change the display format in you `select` query the way you want using the [Mysql Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done for the table; besides, you even cannot change this default value at all.

The answer is a server variable [**datetime_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datetime_format), it is unused.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim x as date 

x = dr("appdate")
appdate = x.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

dr is the variable of datareader

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DATE NOT NULL FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```