# how to display the date from the MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql: Setup the format of DATETIME to 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' when creating a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab)

how to display the date in DD-MM-YYYY from the database. Where it shows only in YYYY-MM-DD
I have add the date in mysql using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). Please give me a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the default format, but you can specify it explicitly, like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_column_name`, '%d-%m-%Y') ...
```