# Change date format in mySql database table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Morning everyone. Just a quick question. In my existing MySql database I've few columns with dates in it. Currently these are *yyyy-mm-dd* format but now I need to change it all to **dd-mm-yyyy** format. I've tried `select date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y');` but it doesnt update existing data in my table.Is there any easy way of doing it? Or even if its not easy could you give me some suggestion how to do it please and thank you.

Comment: See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Try using`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateColumn FROM table
```

Comment: It kinda works Vijaykumar. It shows me the single column and the format is changed. But when I go back to my table the content is not affected by my query

Comment: yes that's obvious,if you want this data you can redirect to some other table in your database + if this is working pls accept the answer

Comment: INSERT INTO stocks_remaining(DATE_FORMAT(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"), Item, Quantity) VALUES("02/05/2017", "mouse", 2)    What would be the right syntax for this

Answer (score 1):

You cann't able to change the default `date` format in table. Default `DATE` format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. But you can able to retrive the `date` column value as your way.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its very handy