# SQL CHANGE DATE FORMAT IN BULK

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with several hundred fields but my data structure is wrong. It is currently in uk format as follows:

```
d/m /y
01/01/85
01/01/96
23/12/87
```

What would be the most efficient way to change the dates in bulk to sql standard of year/month/day

```
eg.
02/01/85 --> 1985/01/02
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change date format in mySql database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046978/change-date-format-in-mysql-database-table)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) type column in your table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE myTable ADD newColumn DATE;
   ```
2. Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to parse the existing values into your new column:

   ```
   UPDATE myTable SET newColumn = STR_TO_DATE(oldColumn, '%d/%m/%y');
   ```
3. Change your codebase to use the new column.  If this can't happen immediately, you could define `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) to keep the new column consistent with the old one:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER myTable_bi BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
     SET NEW.newColumn = STR_TO_DATE(oldColumn, '%d/%m/%y');

   CREATE TRIGGER myTable_bu BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
     SET NEW.newColumn = STR_TO_DATE(oldColumn, '%d/%m/%y');
   ```
4. Drop the old column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE myTable DROP oldColumn;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**select date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')** use this to change it to required format.I have used `date_format` function. You can get more information about `date_format` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)