# Remove unnecessary string and Update date format in MySql

Tags: mysql, date

Basically my date in MySql table looks like this

```
2001-04-16
```

The format is actually `day-month-year`. Unfortunately `20` is added to the date. So finally i should update this date. This should become

```
01-04-2016
```

How to update my all date format in my table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: Setup the format of DATETIME to 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' when creating a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab)

Answer (score 1):

Don't change this in the database, change it when you need to display it. The [ISO date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is what's used internally and should be kept that way, it's the most native, efficient format, and it sorts correctly.

You can select them out:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM table_name
```

Using the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Even better is to do this in your application layer, whatever that is, using a date formatting function tuned to the user's locale.

If you've got a bunch of bad data in your database you need to convert, you can re-write it with the `DATE_FORMAT()` function to strip out the mistakes.

For example:

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_column=DATE_FORMAT('20%d-%m-%y', date_column)
```

Comment: This is actually returning null. I have date column type as 'DATE'

Comment: My example had the arguments in the reverse order, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql, MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. so you can fetch date in whatever format you want from database, please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html for more info.

you can use DATE_FORMAT() function :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%d-%m-%Y', date) as desired_date FROM table_name where 1
```