# yyyy-MM-ddT00:00 & yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00

Tags: mybatis

In MyBatis(mysql) when I select a datetime it returns a LocalDateTime field.
* When the DB value is `2017-11-06 12:00:00` the field value is `2017-11-06T12:00:00`
* But when the DB value is `2017-11-06 00:00:00` the field vaule is ***`2017-11-06T00:00`***

It is not `2017-11-06T00:00:00` - that is it's getting without 'seconds' in the time.

What could be the reason ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert in MySQL but the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab) looks like it might help you.