# Converting Hours format to hh:mm:format in MySql

Tags: mysql

Currently I'm doing this in SQL:

```
    select emp_code,in_time,out_time,worked_time,WT,shift_work_time,
    case when enable_overtime = 1 and TIMEDIFF(WT,shift_work_time) > 0
then hour(TIMEDIFF(WT,(shift_work_time))) else 0 end as OT
FROM myTable;
```

I am getting wrong OT at line 8,because shift_work_time is in hours format,so i want to convert shift_worke_time which is in hours to hh:mm:ss how can i do this?
Thank you in advance

I have also tried
`TIME_FORMAT(shift_worke_time, '%H:%i:%s')` but when shift_worke_time is `10` output is `00:00:10` but it should be

```
10:00:00
```

Comment: check here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `STR_TO_DATE`(shift_worke_time,'%H')

```
 SELECT 
  select emp_code,in_time,out_time,worked_time,WT,(shift_worke_time,'%H') as shift_worke_time,
    case when enable_overtime = 1 and TIMEDIFF(WT,(shift_worke_time,'%H')) > 0
then hour(TIMEDIFF(WT,(shift_worke_time,'%H'))) else 0 end as OT
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,I want to format shift_worke_time which is in if condition and I am  getting 00:00 in output

Comment: then you have to use case when

Comment: @user9862376 edited my answer by using case when check please

Comment: it  works only  when my shift_worke_time is 10 but does not give output when my shift_worke_time is 10:00:00

Comment: @user9862376 in that you can use TIME_FORMAT("19:30:10", "%H %i %s"); this formating

Comment: I have used TIMEDIFF(WT,STR_TO_DATE(shift_worke_time,'%H ') is that correct