# MYSQL can't update date but in happens very seldom

Tags: mysql

**MYSQL can't update date but in happens very seldom**

I have it error very seldom(few time by month),for some dates like this. It isn't problem of code. I can't update DB field with the same date by IDE too.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
> value: '2022-03-13 02:59:14' for column 'date' at row 1 (SQL: update
> `logs` set `logs`.`date` = 2022-03-13 02:59:14 where `ID` = 2)

**Other date not updates**: 2022-03-13 02:58:16, 2022-03-13 02:57:15, 2022-03-13 02:55:15, 2022-03-13 02:54:16, 2022-03-13 02:53:14, 2022-03-13 02:52:15, 2022-03-13 02:51:15 .

**Updates successfully**: 2022-04-11 09:17:07

**My query:**

> update logs set logs.date = '2022-03-13 02:59:14' where ID = 2;

Guys do you have any ideas, why in happens?

**Table info:**

[image]

**DB info:**

> Dialect: MySQL  DBMS: MySQL (ver. 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
>
> Case sensitivity: plain=exact, delimited=exact
>
> Driver: MariaDB Connector/J (ver. 2.6.0, JDBC4.2)

> charset = utf8;

Comment: I think you have to specify the datetime format: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338122/7030060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with these values. See below
Please give us the table definition and actuel sql update query that you are running.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE d (d datetime);
> INSERT INTO d VALUES ('2022-02-02');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:58:16';
>  select d from d;
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:57:15';
>  select d from d;
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:55:15';
>  select d from d;
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:54:16';
>  select d from d;
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:53:14';
>  select d from d;
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:52:15';
>  select d from d;
>  update d set d = '2022-03-13 02:51:15';
>  select d from d;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:58:16 |
>
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:57:15 |
>
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:55:15 |
>
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:54:16 |
>
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:53:14 |
>
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:52:15 |
>
> ✓
>
> | d                   |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-03-13 02:51:15 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9c65324047312173072eee1978ee0481)*

Comment: @Ivan Pirus What did you do differently that this answer corrected?

Comment: @Kendle I add Table info and table info

Comment: @P.Salmon I did test. I understood that a problem in a DB

Comment: There is a problem with the DB build version or something else. Fine: MariaDB (ver. 10.4.19-MariaDB-1:10.4.19+maria~focal), MariaDB (ver. 10.4.17-MariaDB-1:10.4.17+maria~focal). Not good, problems with date: MySQL (ver. 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Comment: @Kendle pls edit post add my answer below, what I wrote in a last my comment. And I will vote again.

Comment: Ivan: I've checked and it seems to be working in all versions of mariaDB on DBfiddle see. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=de8c156d1a63acb21b6ee35100b670b9

Comment: Obviously if it's a date column it won't record the time

Comment: @Kendle Ok. I mean it is a problem of current installed DB or something else on server. I tested it on the beta server no problems too. Not big deal, thank for help

Comment: TIMESTAMP supports date time

Comment: @Kendle I had field type timestamp. I changed to datetime. Problem solved. Pls add variant answer below. Like Try to change field type timestamp to datetime

Comment: Ivan Glad you've solved the problem. My example works fine with datatype `timestamp` - see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3563bcc2c2ca020a714c535df8938b5d - there must be something more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243857/discussion-between-ivan-pirus-and-kendle).